# PHP variables not showing up after submitting form (closed)

Tags: php, html

I'm just starting to learn form and PHP.  I am testing a simple HTML file from W3Schools here with the following code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to pass the information to a PHP file called welcome.php, which looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?><br>
Random thing: <?php $rand = "bananas";  echo "$rand"; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the HTML file on Chrome, fill in the name and the email and press submit, the page looks like this:

Welcome
Your email address is:
Random thing:

While the HTML part works, the name variable, email variable and rand variable isn't printed.

[EDIT]: I solved it by transferring the files to a server and running it by going onto the actual webpage and it worked.  Also  Azeez Kallayi suggested running it on Xamp.

Comment: You have error in your code .. missing semicolon after `$rand = "bananas"`

Comment: I think you are not using any server, just opening in broswer without any server, either use wamp or xamp or any other. Also semilcolon as in the above comment

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out. I added the semicolons, but the variables still aren't printing.

Comment: @Azeez Kallayi Running it on a server worked, thank you.

Comment: @AzeezKallayi this should be an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @AzeezKallayi you should add your comment as answer with more details, so OP can accept

Comment: Yes, if it is possible @Azeez Kallayi

Comment: @RosaryLightningX , hering, Masivuye Cokile added as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not using any server, just opening in broswer without any server. Also correct semicolon as in the above comment.

Since PHP is a server side programming language , you need a server to execute the PHP scripts.

There are many applications available that you can use as local servers and run your application. Some of them are below.

[Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [Xamp](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html), [Lamp](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/installer)

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
echo "$rand";
```

To this

```
echo $rand;
```

Comment: this wont give any change,

Comment: Not really, just correcting since I can't comment yet

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should get knowledge what PHP is and how you can use it.

[PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) is a server-side scripting language. So if you try to run it like a html file you will not see the expected output. You need to understand what is a server side [server-side scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) is.

If you have have jumped into coding is very essential you should know how you should debug to resolve your error.

One easy way is to enable error reporting.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
```

Hope this will give you a start .

Comment: Thank you thank you, I don't have much experience working with server-side scripting, this will be very useful.